# How to create a Log when extracting archieves

Tags: bash

I want to create a log file whilst my script extracts 7z

I'm using the following:

```
7z x "*.7z"
mv *.7z Archive
mv *.mp4 Extracted
```

I just wanna make a log file for the extraction but not when moving files...

Answer (score 0):

Simply redirect stdout and stderr to append your log file:

```
7z x "*.7z" >> logfile.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried that before posting but I get the same result, terminal stops displaying output and the log file is blank...